# Netty's FixedChannelPoolMap cannot maintain old channel?

Tags: java, tcp, network-programming, netty

I'm setting up a client application by netty, and want to community whit the other server. Before communication, each tcp connection needs send a login message to login. And then, these tcp connection can send other message.

I use FixedChannelPoolMap maintain my channels for multiplexing, 
According to the connection count, login all the connection in the pool when my program startup.

It looks good. But after a few days of application deployment,
request cannot invoke acquire function fetch old channel that had login 
but invoke create function create a new channel. like that,

```
channel[] ch;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Future<Channel> channelFuture = pool.acquire().sync();
    if (channelFuture.isSuccess()) {
        ch[i] = channelFuture.getNow()
        ch[i].writeAndFlush(LOGIN_REQ);
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    pool.release(ch[i])
}
```

Is this normal? How can i control the FixedChannelPoolMap without creating a new channel?

Comment: The only situation where I would expect the channel pool to create a new channel is if the old channel has disconnected.

Comment: I confirm those channels in the pool hadn't been closed, because I had add Idlehandler for keeping tcp being alive